# How to use OAuth2 in Google's Blogger API V3 in C#

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am trying to authenticate using OAuth in Blogger API V3 in C# from my .Net application.
I've set up an OAuth client ID in Google Cloud Console.

Here's my relevant code:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { BloggerService.Scope.Blogger };

var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
{
    ClientId = "xxxxxxxx",
    ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxx"
};

var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    clientSecrets,
    scopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None
);
```

This opens a "Sign in with Google" page in the browser, but displays an error:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:62643/authorize/
```

The port in the displayed redirect_uri is different every time, so I can't register a redirect URI in my OAuth client ID in Google Cloud Console because it's different every time.

So how do I get OAuth working with Blogger API V3?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Console requires a pre-registered redirect URI for security reasons, and a dynamic port like `62643` won't work. The issue you're facing is the dynamic port assignment when running your application locally.

Try setting up a local web server like IIS Express or Kestrel for development. These servers allow you to configure a specific port for your application.

Then update your code to use the fixed port assigned by the local server instead of relying on the dynamic port. This allows you to register the exact redirect URI (e.g.,http://localhost:5000/authorize/) in the Google Cloud Console for your OAuth client ID.